# Why garbage collector is not collecting dbcontext objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, garbage-collection, dbcontext

I'm using the following code to insert or update object.

The context or any object is not returned outside of the method. So no object is referenced outside of the method. But if i keep the loop going, i need up using 2 GB or memory at some point.

On checking turns out objects are never removed from memory. Even though I have used new contexts within using blocks. Why garbage collector isnt collecting those objects. Also tried GC.Collect() but nothing changes. What am I doing wrong?

Updated Code:

I think using a extension method was the issue. I'd love know what exactly and how exactly fixed it but the following code checked my memory leak

Comment: "Why garbage collector isnt collecting those objects" - what objects? the contexts?

Comment: If you want to find memory leak, then memory profiler is your best friend. But, your method looks like a nightmare. Why don't create *single* context outside of the method *and* `for` loop, and use it during add/update routine? Furthermore, `AddOrUpdate` definitely must be broken onto number of small methods.

Comment: By objects i meant Dbcontext.movy and it's children

Comment: I'm working on  breaking the method for updating it's children.

Answer (score 2):

GC collects all unused objects (accept for the open streams and connections), so GC is not the problem - it`s in the code. Try splitting your code into separate methods/clases based on SOLID. Then memory profiler if needed.

There is no chance to degug your code without your Database. So just general answer, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what could be the possible reasons that I'm ending up with 100s of objects in my memory. Since the method is  isn't returning anything.

Comment: try to avoid extension method, might be the reason (unlikelly though). Also try to debug after commenting parts of the code - starting with the single context.

Comment: Will try with a single context n let u know. Initially my code was under a single context but it was causing 100% cpu to savechange() as more n more objects are  added to context detectchanges() becomes more expensive every time.

Comment: Also noticed that you create same context new TMDB() many times. There is no way to use one ?

Comment: I did use one context before. But as  I mentioned in my earlier comment it was causing high cpu. But I will give it another try.

Comment: Thanks to vladimir, i think not using the extension method worked. and i also broke my long method to short methods and it works now.

Comment: Once deployed to server it started to hog up memory again. No clue.

Comment: I'm seeing a constant rise on Process Memory, but eventually GC clears it to 250 MB once it reaches 1.2GB.

Comment: I had to call GC.Collect manually after each memory expensive update to free up memory and it came downlaod to 300 MB.